# Create A model In Django Which Accept Value For A Specific Choice

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I Am Working In Django & DRF(Django-Rest-Framework) In Which I have A Choices In which if Video Is Paid Video , Now I'm creating another Model which Stores all Paid Video's Information

```
from django.db import models
from  userapi.models import User
# from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
import datetime

class post(models.Model) : 
    Public = 'Pub'
    Private = 'Pri'
    Paid = 'Paid'
    selection = [
        (Public, 'Public'),
        (Private, 'Followers'),
        (Paid, 'Paid'),
    ]
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    post_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    post_selection = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=selection)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

This is userpost.py
now I want to create model named paid_videos in which If post_selection is Paid then It takes amount of it

I'm NEW TO DJANGO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that :

```
post.objects.create(post_selection="Public")
```

Just pass the string as an argument.

However there is few problem with your code :

- You need to name your class with a capitalise letter so for you post -> Post
- selection is a constant as such it is better to make uppercase "SELECTION"

A good example is from the documentation:

```
class Student(models.Model):
FRESHMAN = 'FR'
SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
JUNIOR = 'JR'
SENIOR = 'SR'
GRADUATE = 'GR'
YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
    (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
    (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
    (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
    (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
    (GRADUATE, 'Graduate'),
]
year_in_school = models.CharField(
    max_length=2,
    choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
    default=FRESHMAN,
)
```

This is easier to read and it has default value so not integrity error will arise on your code